# African Pentecostal Witch Hunting Guide real?

Tags: religion, books, violence, africa

I found this online: "[The African Pentecostal Church's Guide of Inquisitions of Witches and Magicians in the African Continent - 1989](http://www.zoklet.net/totse/en/religion/miscellaneous_religious_texts/africanpenteco173932.html) (Translated from the Swahili Manuscript of the late Bakari Sudi Jabari)"

I can't find any reliable sources to verify such a thing really existed, but I do know that [alleged witches](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=33h_h7mtoN0) are [still](http://blog.newhumanist.org.uk/2012/07/resurgance-of-witch-hunts-in-nigeria.html) [being burned to death](http://www.liveleak.com/view?i=ab5_1237210736) in [parts](http://harlcazz.bravepages.com/library/Paganism/Pagan%20History%20and%20Facts/Witchhunts%20in%20Africa.htm) [of](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/africa/575178.stm) [Africa](http://www.liveleak.com/view?i=1fe_1310865020) ([mostly](http://mikemccormack.blogspot.nl/2009/01/nigerian-child-witches-hate-and-hope.html) [Nigeria](http://www.google.com/hostednews/afp/article/ALeqM5gylWH14V9Bv6kGBv39p4N06laoNA), it seems).

So, is this new [Malleus Maleficarum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malleus_Maleficarum) real? I.e.: **Was this guide really used by a Pentecostal church or its believers?**

Update: I've removed the limit to Africa as I'm absolutely shocked to find such [occurring in the UK](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-london-17040111).

Comment: Wait, what is the question?

Comment: Whether there really is such a guide or this is just a made up horror story from the internet.

Comment: So you're asking if the book exists, not if its contents are legitimate?

Comment: Sounds more like "was this a publication which was meant to be taken seriously when published and is not some elaborate hoax to condemn African Pentacostals"

Comment: You don't need to limit this to Africa - we've had a spate of such "witch" killings ... In the UK. In the last year. Usually linked with immigrant African populations, but still: really off-the-chart freaky.

Comment: One occurrence on the internet, taken down and now only preserved in an archive. I would really say the chances of this being real are tiny.

Comment: Is anyone claiming that the document is real?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, it's part of a collection of religious texts, so the context is that of serious study.

Comment: Not an answer, but [this news article](http://freethinker.co.uk/2013/12/19/kenyan-pentecostal-preachers-burn-hiv-medication-tell-sufferers-that-only-prayer-will-cure-them/) gives me the chills.

Comment: The link is gone, and that was the only source on Google to feature the title of the alleged book other than this question. The names "Bakari Sudi Jabari" do appear elsewhere, however, as three consecutive suggestions for boy's (first) names from Africa in [The Little Big Book of Pregnancy](https://issuu.com/welcomebooks/docs/littlebigbookofpregnancy/236).